# SQL Server trigger validation to insert or update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have to develop a trigger for multiple value update for the `Change_Table` that contains two columns `Article_C` (primary key) and `Status_C`. The trigger activates when the `Status_C` column is updated and it needs to either insert or update the `Target_Table`which columns are `Article_T` (primary key) and `Status_T`.

The Status column for both tables is a `NOT NULL int`

For `insert` validation: insert all `Change_Table` values (Articles & Status) that do not exist into the `Target_Table`.

For `update` condition: if the articles exist in the `Target_Table`, pass the updated status value to that table.

Status values are 1 or 2.

My current implementation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Article_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[Change_Table]
AFTER UPDATE 
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
AS
    IF UPDATE (Status_C)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Target_Table (Article_T, Status_T)
            SELECT Article_C, Status_C
            FROM Change_Table
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Target_Table 
                              WHERE Change_Table.Article_C = Target_Table.Article_T 
                                AND Change_Table.Status_C = Target_Table.Status_T)
    END
```

This is a rough idea of the insert but it only works once when the `Change_Table` is first updated and the target table is empty. After that I get an error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" due to duplicate primary key after updating the status for a second time due to the insert condition.

Query that gave error after second execution:

```
update Change_Table set status_c = 1 where Article_C in (1000,1003)
```

How can I modify this query to implement the update status condition to this trigger?

Comment: Start with the basics. What, in fact, are the primary keys of both tables as well as any unique constraints or indexes? Your code does not refer to `Article_Num` AT ALL. Did you add errors by attempting to anonymize your super-secret schema?

Comment: @SMor The only error was in the description which I added `Article_Num` instead of `Article_C`

Comment: @SMor Please, please can we have a canonical ["The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers"](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) meaning that `inserted` and `deleted` are not checked at all, or not checked for multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `deleted` or `inserted` tables. These 2 virtual tables are working nicely with trigger. In you example, you may not need `deleted` table as you are not logging the historical changes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Article_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[Change_Table]
AFTER UPDATE 
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
AS
    IF UPDATE (Status_C)
    BEGIN

        --insert if not exist
       
        INSERT INTO Target_Table
        SELECT A.Article_C, A.Status_C
        FROM inserted as A --the updated records from the source table will exist in the inserted virtual table
        LEFT JOIN  Target_Table as B
        ON B.Article_T = A.Article_C
        WHERE B.Article_T IS NULL

        --update if exist
       
        UPDATE A
        SET A.Status_T = B.Article_C
        FROM Target_Table as A
        INNER JOIN  inserted as B   --the updated records from the source table will exist in the inserted virtual table
        ON B.Article_C = A.Article_T

    END
```

Comment: Why change a `NOT EXISTS` to `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` when the former is more performant? I note you are not checking `deleted` in case the row hasn't actually changed

Comment: You will want to update first and then insert - since the opposite logic will update the newly inserted rows - but this is the appropriate general approach. IF UPDATE does not do what people think it does (and what lazy coders cause) - one needs to check the old (deleted) and new (inserted) values to know if an actual change occurred.